# No entiendo una cosa con las funciones y con la variable

Tags: python, funciones, variables

```py
print("programa de evaluacion de notas")

nota_alumno = int(input("introduce la nota del alumno"))

def evaluacion(nota):
    valoracion = "aprobado"
    if nota < 5:
        valoracion = "suspendido"
    return valoracion

print(evaluacion(nota_alumno))
```

Porque me sirve `nota_alumno` si tengo definido `valoracion` y `nota` solamente?

Comment: El parámetro puede tener cualquier nombre, puede ser `x`, `y`, `variable` ,`nota`, cuando llamas a la función le debes pasar un parámetro, que puede ser cualquier variable que tengas, el parámetro servirá como un *alias* para operar con tal valor que recibe la funcion

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Tu duda es una cuestion conceptual.

### Parametros formales y actuales.

- Los **parametros formales** son aquellos especificados en la cabecera de la función. Los parámetros formales sólo se conocen dentro de la función.
- Los **parametros actuales** son las expresiones pasadas como argumentos en la llamada a una función.

En tu caso `nota` es un parametro formal declarado y conocido solo dentro de la función `evaluacion`.
`nota_alumno`, por otro lado, es tu parametro real que se utiliza en el bloque principal obteniendo el input y pasando el valor obtenido a tu función para su procesamiento.
`valoracion` es una variable interna de tu función y no cae en ninguna de estas dos categorías

Answer (score 1):

Muchos se van a echar las manos a la cabeza con esta respuesta, pero...

***nota_alumno* se convierte en *nota* dentro de la función**, no mantiene su nombre de *nota_alumno*. Básicamente, al ejecutar la función *evaluacion(nota_alumno)*, lo que hace la función es decir que *nota* tiene el valor de *nota_alumno*, que es lo que se pone en el teclado.

Puedes hacer lo mismo sin necesidad de *nota_alumno*, que es una variable que usas de paso para hacer más legible el código:

```
def evaluacion(nota):
    valoracion = "aprobado"
    if nota < 5:
        valoracion = "suspendido"
    return valoracion

print(evaluacion(int(input("introduce la nota del alumno: "))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que al definir tu función tu método recibe un parámetro o argumento que se llama nota, y esta es obligatoria, es decir tu método siempre debe recibir un valor cuando haces un llamado.

`nota_alumno` es igual al input que se introduce y tu función lo recibe como el parámetro obligatorio, dentro del alcance de tu método `nota_alumno` es igual a nota, y para fines de uso lo manejas siempre como nota dentro de tu método incluso puedes llamar tu método así:

```py
evaluacion(4)
evaluacion(nota=nota_alumno)
```

Espero te sirva de algo.
Saludos

Comment: te equivocas al decir método, pues un método es una función pero de una clase, mientras que las funciones son eso, funciones

Answer (score 0):

Voy a hacer una respuesta recopilando lo que se ha venido diciendo, todos están en lo correcto, sin embargo las respuestas me parecen algo incompletas.

## ¿Qué es una función?

Una función permite definir un bloque reutilizable, es decir que pueda usarse múltiples veces, esto permite crear un código mas modular. La función debe de realiza una operación en concreta, esto para que cumpla con lo antes dicho. En Python una función se define con la palabra reservada `def` seguido del nombre de la función y entre paréntesis van los argumentos `def nombre(argumentos)`

A una función la función se le puede poner opcionalmente una cadena de texto literal; esta es la cadena de texto de documentación de la función, o *docstring*. de esta forma

```py
def evaluacion(nota):
    """ Funcion para evaluar a un estudiante."""
    ...
```

Como dije una función recibe **argumentos* o también conocidos como *parámetros*, de lo cual hablaremos ahora, gracias a la respuesta de [@cachique](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/9291/cachique)

## Argumentos o Parámetros

- Los parámetros formales son aquellos especificados en la cabecera de la función. Los parámetros formales sólo se conocen dentro de la función.
- Los parámetros actuales son las expresiones pasadas como argumentos en la llamada a una función.

En tu caso `nota` es un parámetro formal declarado y conocido solo dentro de la función evaluación.
Esto tiene que ver con el *scope* de una función, pues las variables declaradas en el parámetro de esta función solo existen dentro de esta.

`nota_alumno`, por otro lado, es el valor que recibirá tu parámetro real que se utiliza en el bloque principal obteniendo el `input` y pasando el valor obtenido a tu función para su procesamiento.
`valoracion` es una variable interna de tu función y no cae en ninguna de estas dos categorías

Dada esta explicación existe varias formas de pasar los parámetros a una función, si una función tiene un parámetro llamado `name`, de esta forma `def saludar(name)`, se puede hacer referencia a este parámetro y asignarle un valor, hay un ejemplo en la respuesta de [@JuanOcampo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/230237/juan-ocampo)

## Uso de un parámetro

`nota_alumno` es igual al `input` que se introduce y tu función lo recibe como el parámetro obligatorio. Dentro del alcance de tu función `nota_alumno` es igual a `nota`, y para fines de uso lo manejas siempre como `nota` dentro de tu función incluso puedes llamar tu método así:

```py
evaluacion(4)
evaluacion(nota=nota_alumno)
```

Una forma simplificade de pasarle el parametro es como lo hace [@IvánUría](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/230302/iv%c3%a1n-ur%c3%ada) en su ejemplo

```py
def evaluacion(nota):
    valoracion = "aprobado"
    if nota < 5:
        valoracion = "suspendido"
    return valoracion

print(evaluacion(int(input("introduce la nota del alumno: "))))
```

**Explicacion**

> `nota_alumno` se convierte en `nota` dentro de la función, no mantiene su nombre de `nota_alumno`. Básicamente, al ejecutar la función `evaluacion(nota_alumno)`, lo que hace la función es decir que nota tiene el valor de `nota_alumno`, que es lo que se pone en el teclado.
> Puedes hacer lo mismo sin necesidad de `nota_alumno`

Espero que la redacción te hay servido y aclarado tus dudas